# How to store escaped characters in MySQL and display them in php?

Tags: php, mysql, text, html-escape-characters

For example I want to store the String "That's all". MySQL automatically escapes the ' character. How do I echo that String from the database using php but remove the \ in front of escaped characters like \' ? I would also like to preserve other formatting like new lines and blank spaces.

Comment: I think you misunderstand escaping. The back-slashes are added when within a statement to avoid conflicting with apostrophes in SQL queries, but they’re not actually added to the database.

Comment: My database table says otherwise. I understand what escaping does. I am not escaping any characters myself, however the characters are escaped in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `stripslashes()`, regarding the linebreaks just use the `nl2br()` function.

Example:

```
$yourString = "That\'s all\n folks";
$yourString = stripslashes(nl2br($yourString));
echo $yourString;
```

Note: `\\` double slashes will turn to `\` single slashes

---

You should probably setup your own function, something like:

```
$yourString = "That\'s all\n folks";

function escapeString($string) {
    return stripslashes(nl2br($string));
}

echo escapeString($yourString);
```

There are also several good examples in the `nl2br()` [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

---

**Edit 2**

The reason your are seeing these is because mysql is escaping line breaks, etc. I am guessing you are using `mysql_*` functions. You should probably look into `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Here is an example:

```
$yourString = "That's all
 folks";
echo mysql_escape_string($yourString);
```

Outputs:

> That\'s all\r\n folks

Comment: Do I use than when I am echoing or storing in the database?

Comment: You would use it when you are echoing. Also, I just read about the `\n` (new line) portion of your OP. How is that being represented in the database? As `\\n`?

Comment: In the database table, the text with new lines just shows the lines being blank. there are now \n characters in it, which I find odd.

Comment: There are also 4 tab spaces in front of the text when displaying, but they aren't in the database. is stripslashes() causing this? Wasn't there before.

Comment: See my changes above, `nl2br` should fix your issues. Check out the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) for more examples

Comment: now it just echos a bunch of tab spaces, but the text is in the database

Comment: Can you provide me with a string from your database showing all of these characters you're getting? Please paste it in your OP.

Comment: from db (comments arent showing line breaks):
quote\'s test
line 1
line 2

line 4

Comment: I figured it out.. I had blank space inside my `<textarea></textarea>`... /facepalm

Comment: :) It happens to the best of us, glad you got it working. Best of luck!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26495/discussion-between-xzar-and-asok)

Answer (score 1):

If you use prepared statements, those characters will not be escaped on insert.

Use `stripslashes()` to remove slashes if you cannot avoid adding slashes on input.

Comment: I'm simply adding the text to the table, not changing anything about it. MySQL is doing the escaping itself.

Answer (score -1):

At first, magic_quotes_gpc escapes the character like ' or ". You can also disable this in your php.ini. But then you should escape the things yourself that no query can get "infected".
Lookup mysql injection for more information.

When the escaped string is been written in your database. The string doesn't contain theses escape charakters and when you output them again. You should see the result as you want it.

Me for myself prefer the method by storing everything without escapes and escape or display things when I output them. You could also easily use an `str_replace("\n", "", $text)` to prevent newslines are displayed.

Greetings MRu

Comment: Then you can do it the other way around. `str_replace('  ', ' &nbsp;', $text)` is for the spaces and you can use `nl2br($text)` to replace the newlines with the html element <br> (or <br/>, i don't know any more)