# Issue with mysql store

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I Have problem with database

this is the input

```
<p><img src="http://something.com/img.jpg" alt="" width="90" height="100" /></p>
```

this is how i found it in mysql

```
 <p><img src=\"http://something.com/img.jpg" alt=\"\" width=\"701\" height=\"233\" /></p>
```

"inset im mysql code"

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO blog_posts_seo (postTitle,postSlug,postDesc,postCont,postDate) VALUES (:postTitle, :postSlug, :postDesc, :postCont, :postDate)') ;
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':postTitle' => $postTitle,
                ':postSlug' => $postSlug,
                ':postDesc' => $postDesc,
                ':postCont' => $postCont,
                ':postDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ));
            $postID = $db->lastInsertId();
```

don`t know where these slashes came from and this cause link issues as that link open like this

```
mysite.com//"http://something.com/img.jpg\"
```

---

fixed by adding this to php.ini

```
    magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Comment: Use prepared statements to store data in mysql.Or look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510082/how-to-store-escaped-characters-in-mysql-and-display-them-in-php

Comment: These slashes seems to be here to protect double quotes during an insert into db statement. Maybe something wrong with this statement. Can you show it ? If you use single quotes in your insert statement you don't need to protect double-quotes with a slash

Comment: TNX fixed by magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so