# Image link insertion in database without \

Tags: php, mysql, editor

I am using an editor to create page. its an editor which we have in joomla. I am choosing image and uploading it and its visible in the editor and now i uplad it to the database i.e. mysql using php insert method.

Now when i fetch the data on localhost from table it shows the image to me but when i do the same thing on windows hosting the image is not shown.

I had checked the database of localhost and i found there the link of the image is `<img src="http://i.imgur.com/mVjaPYE.jpg">`  but when i checked it on wu=indows hosting i get `<img src=\"http://i.imgur.com/HKqFMdx.jpg\" width=\"470\">`

Its including \ while uploading the image. and when i fetch it , i cand get my image.

Help me guys.

Comment: You're looking for stripslashes() or other suggestions found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510082/how-to-store-escaped-characters-in-mysql-and-display-them-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print it, use stripslashes($img);

http://php.net//manual/bg/function.stripslashes.php

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows hosting appears to have [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on.

Get hosting with a modern version of PHP installed. The feature was removed in PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

I general unless you are passing your images around to other apps you should never save direct links like that.

your solution

```
$src = (Databas_entry);
$src = str_replace ("\", "", $src);
```

NOTE: do not strip slashes you will lose the important "//" you have in location.